# Get nth element from VBA string array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How would I extract the nth element from a VBA string array?

I have a string, like: `TEST - 2017/01/20 = Invoice`

I wish to extract out the 2nd and 3rd elements as concisely as possible.  I was trying something Javascripty like this, which doesn't work, so there must be a VBA way:

```
Dim Report As String
Dim CurrLine As String
Dim CurrDate As String
Dim CurrTask As String

CurrLine = "TEST - 2017/01/20 = Invoice"
CurrDate = Trim(Split(CurrLine, '-')[1])
CurrTask = Trim(Split(CurrLine, '=')[1])
Report = Report & CHR(34) & CurrDate & CHR(34) & "," & CHR(34) & CurrTask & CHR(34)

//result: "2017/01/20","Invoice"
```

Comment: that seems like a pretty inefficient way to generate CSV because of the many string concatenations, so if it starts to get too slow you can `Join` the strings and replace all with single Regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a possible solution

```
Dim Report As String
Dim CurrLine As String
Dim CurrDate As String
Dim CurrTask As String, St 


CurrLine = "TEST - 2017/01/20 = Invoice"
St=Split(replace(CurrLine, "=","-"),"-")
CurrDate = St(1)
CurrTask = St(2)
Report = Report & CHR(34) & CurrDate & CHR(34) & "," & CHR(34) & CurrTask & CHR(34)  //result: "2017/01/20","Invoice"
```

Comment: Looking to be efficient, can I also do this: `Dim Report as String, CurrLine, CurrDate, CurrTask, St` ? *The goal being to do as much on a single line as possible*

Comment: absolutely, however currline and followings will have data type variant, not string

Comment: So I can leave out the `as String` bit and just use `Dim Report, CurrLine, CurrDate, CurrTask, St` and the code will still work just fine..?

Comment: Thanks - you solved my problem(s). Trust Microsoft to be out of step. I was in the VBA editor and used Ctrl+Z to undo a few changes, then used Ctrl+Y to put them back... I will be bald because of Microsoft.

Comment: @crashwap eeeer not great form, if you want to do it in a single line use the format: Dim a as long, b as string, c as Double.  If you leave out the dimensioning they will be variants, which is what's needed for st in this case, but it's not really appropriate for the rest

Comment: `Dim St() As String` or `Dim St$()` as `Split` always returns String array

Answer (score 3):

I would have used the solution of @h2so4 with replacement (especially if it is a job related task), but if you are a fan of "fancy" coding, this works as well:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim strtest As String

    strtest = "Test - 2017 / 1 / 20 = Invoice"

    Debug.Print Trim(Split(strtest, "-")(1))
    Debug.Print Trim(Split(strtest, "=")(1))
    Debug.Print Trim(Split(Trim(Split(strtest, "-")(1)), "=")(0))

End Sub
```